# Differing URL in Args before and after navigating in WebView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I currently have a `WebView` that I am using in the app. I hook into both the `Navigating` and `Navigated` events but I am noticing that the `URL` that I am getting back is different. The one in the `Navigated` event seems to be less specific.

URL from `Navigating`:

> https://www.google.com/setprefs?sig=0_4XYi9X3t3qq0PFZcM9y00__3scE%3D&hl=af&source=homepage&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisx8Droa7bAhXMO5oKHfUZAnwQ2ZgBCA8

URL from `Navigated`:

> https://www.google.com/

Why are they so different?

Comment: Is that on iOS?

Comment: @hichame.yessou yes

Comment: Not sure about the reasons, but from the source code, there is a specific difference in the URLs between the Navigated and Navigating event. Not sure about that but I assume that it's for allowing to go back while navigating. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/578c0eb23a719926f90f0fd45ff1659512bb9bed/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/WebViewRenderer.cs#L214